# Apollo / GraphQL / Prisma "Login" Mutation Won't Return All User Fields

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, prisma

I'm relatively new to the world of GraphQL / Prisma / Apollo and working on an app where I need login functionality, and access restrictions based upon a User's permissions.

When I run my login mutation it fails if I request the User's "roles" field to be returned and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

If I do a simple query on all Users and request the "roles" field it returns no problem.
Likewise if I do a query on a single User and filter by any other field: - id, email, username.

My app is setup as this:

datamodel.graphql (prisma)

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id @unique
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  username: String! @unique
  password: String!
  roles: [UserRoles!]!
}

enum UserRoles {
  ADMIN
  USER
  DIRECTOR
}
```

schema.graphql (react / apollo)

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  username: String!
  password: String!
  roles: [UserRoles!]!
}

enum UserRoles {
  ADMIN
  USER
  DIRECTOR
}
```

Mutation.js (resolvers front end)

```
async loginUser(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
    const { username, password } = args.data;
    const user = await prisma.query.user({ where: { username } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("Invalid login credentials. Please try again");
    }

    const passwordIsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordIsMatch) {
      throw new Error("Invalid login credentials. Please try again");
    }

    return {
      user,
      token: generateToken(user.id),
    };
  },
```

If I run the login mutation as something like this it runs fine.

```
mutation LoginUser($username: String!, $password: String!){
  loginUser(data: {
    username: $username
    password: $password
  }) {
    user {
      id
      name
    }
    token
  }
}
```

But if I run it like this it fails with a message of "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.roles."

```
mutation LoginUser($username: String!, $password: String!){
  loginUser(data: {
    username: $username
    password: $password
  }) {
    user {
      id
      name
      roles
    }
    token
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or should I wait for the response on this mutation and then run a query for a user with the id which is returned and then pull the "roles" field from that? That seems a little superfluous to me, as I thought one of the great benefits of GraphQL was minimising the number of http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query fails because the `roles` field was declared as required in your schema, but your resolver obviously returns no roles for the user.

To pass the validation, you need to change the field spec to optional in both GraphQL and Prisma schemas (remove the `!`s):

```
  roles: [UserRoles]
```

Comment: Hi Son, thanks for the response. I actually need user roles to be a required field. i.e. When a user is created, they must have a role assigned. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: @DonMacarthur As you want role required, then the resolver returning no roles for that user is actually a violation of your requirememt, and the validation and rejection error is actually helping you. This is a real problem you need to resolve, not to work around. Find out why and make sure all users have role. Or at least check if roles are empty and return at least one default role. Like adding this before returning from the resolver: `if (!user.roles || !user.roles.length) user.roles = ['default'];`

Comment: As you said Users query return roles fine, then check the `prisma.query.user` that your resolver called; it might be missing the roles from its response.

Comment: Hi again, I found a solution. I checked the line where I am calling prisma.query.user and then added specific fields I was after ie `prisma.query.user( { where: { username } }, "{id name username password email roles}");`. This works for now, but I'm concerned about sending all of those fields to the client. I'm thinking I'll have to factor in fragments to filter the password out after the backend has done it's authentication. I'm not sure why I had to do that as I tried to run the same query with "info" passed as an argument but that didn't work. Anyways, thanks again for the help :-)